# Getting output of 2 queries in one mongodb call from java morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia, mongo-java-driver

I'm fairly new to mongodb but I was wondering if there's a way by which we can get **2 different results** from same mongodb collection in **one** database call uisng mongo java driver with morphia.

I have a collection `accounts` and I'm fetching data based on a key `accountId`. I need below two results/outputs from this collection in one query.

1. count of all the documents where accountID is 'xyz'
2. ResultList of first N documents where accountID is 'xyz' AND resultSet is sorted by a timestamp field.

to resolve the second scenario I'm using:

```
..Query....limit(N).order("TimeField").field("TimeField").filter("accountID =", "xyz").asList();
```

This is working fine as per expectation but to get the total count (scenario 1) of all documents with accountId = 'xyz' needs another mongodb call, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't support such batching on queries, unfortunately.  You'll have to execute two separate calls.